# Django/Mezzanine Shows Default 404 page with DEBUG set to False

Tags: python, django, http-status-code-404, mezzanine

I cannot seem to be able to figure out how to make Mezzanine show custom 404 error pages. Currently it only shows the ones that come with Django by default with the line below saying "You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page."

It is set to false in my application settings, both local and production.

Does it mean I have to set it in some other place?

Comment: Is it really `False`, though? If you do `from django.conf import settings; print settings.DEBUG` on a Python shell, what's the result?

Comment: Got an exception: _django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting DEBUG, but settings are not configured_. But does the django DEBUG settings matter anyway since settings of my application should have a precedence, and there it is definitely set to DEBUG = False?

Comment: `djagno.conf.settings` is the _full_ settings object, it contains your project settings. You are getting the error because you are missing the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` environment variable. If you start the python shell via [`manage.py shell`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-shell), it should work.

Comment: It says False :/ It is also false for the Mezzanine DEBUG setting. Could it be that mezzanine cannot find the 404.html template somehow, so it defaults to the stock one?

Comment: You can look at [the Django source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/handlers/base.py#L140) to see what exactly is going on when you get a 404 error. Did you change the `handler404` in your root urlconf?

Comment: Yes, I did change the handler, that made no difference.

Comment: The default debug page should really only appear if DEBUG is True, so either your [computer is haunted](http://xkcd.com/1316/), or maybe your Django installation is somehow corrupted...?! How did you upgrade Django; can you try to start with a clean virtualenv?

Comment: I created a virtual environment using the latest apps that the website uses, copied the files and DB in and then upgraded the DB using South, which was a lot of pain because the installation was about 2 years out of date. I admit that things seemed to be not holding well together in process but all seems to be working now, except suddenly the error templates getting broken. I'll probably take your suggestion and try to recreate it again from a fresh virtual environment, I really have nothing else to try left.

Comment: @Werdok Did you find a solution?

Comment: @Username, I can't remember if I did, that was a while ago. It was a once off job, never had to deal with Django again after that.